# Reorder the numbers after delete some of them in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a vector [1 2 3 4 ... 100] and another vector storing the numbers I want to delete like [2 3 4]. After deleting, the numbers in original vector should be mapped to another order, for example, 1->1, 5->2, 6->3, etc. Is there any efficient way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What did you try? (I.e. what do you consider the inefficient way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `setdiff`:

```
% original vector
A = 1:100;

% elements to be removed
B = [2 3 4 18 21];

% new order (indices)
C = randperm(numel(A)-numel(B));

% Step 1) remove the elements
[D,I] = setdiff(A,B); % ordered
D = A(I);             % restore original order

% Step 2) re-order the elements
D = D(C)
```

Comment: The new order is not correct...What's the purpose of using C = randperm(numel(A)-numel(B))?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
  original_vector = 1:100;

  delete_vector = [2 3 4];

  for ii = 1:length(delete_vector)
        original_vector(original_vector==delete_vector(ii)) = [];
  end
```

Comment: Small edit: the use of `find` is unnecessary. Moreover, [it's not recommended to use `i` and `j` as loop variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: this only removes the elements, but doesn't re-order them as the OP asked; it is only a partial answer...